# Setting the names of each tab of viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

At the moment I have seven tabs that I are intially just blank, i.e. `""`. Those values would be changed to the values of a `String[]` array that I am passing through a method call shown below

So I have method like this in one of my classes:

```
CustomTabAdapter customTabAdapter = new CustomTabAdapter();
customTabAdapter.setTabNames(temps);
```

Basically this sets the tab names for the `fragmentpager` but it does not update the actual tabs. When I do print `temps` in this class via a `for loop` it prints all the names in `temps` - which means that temps exists but it never updates the tabs.

I believe it doesn't update because I am not overriding the original values in my `CustomTabAdapter` class but here is my `CustomTabAdapter` class:

```
public class CustomTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String names[];
    Context context;

    public CustomTabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
        names = new String[7];
        Arrays.fill(names, "");
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new TabOne();
            case 1:
                return new TabTwo();
            case 2:
                return new TabThree();
            case 3:
                return new TabFour();
            case 4:
                return new TabFive();
            case 5:
                return new TabSix();
            case 6:
                return new TabSeven();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public void setTabNames(String[] input){
        names = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return names[position];
    }
}
```

This is my `TabsGUI` where I display all the tabs:

```
public class TabsViewGUI extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.users_page);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerUsers);
        CustomTabAdapter customTabAdapter = new CustomTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), TabsViewGUI.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customTabAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(customTabAdapter.getCount());
        populate();
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I update the tab names because they don't seem to be updating at the moment

Thanks

Comment: have you tried invalidating the view after you set the tab name?

Comment: No, how do I do that

Comment: try viewPager.invalidate(); right after your setCurrentItem call

Comment: Do you mean in the `public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)` method?

Comment: yeah, that should force android to refresh/redraw that viewPager...

Comment: tell me what happens :)

Comment: i shall do, i am away from `Android Studio` as it is not installed on this PC - was able to get my code through my repo. But I will let you know in a few hours

Comment: just curious what does `viewPager.invalidate();` do? because im just trying to update the tab names with the arraylist that i provided

Comment: Usually the system auto refreshes UI stuff by itself but when It doesn't invalidate() tells the framework that it should redraw that view, happens a lot with resizing. But on a second look into your code... I've noticed that in your adapter you're returning a new Fragment after each getItem() call. You should set the title of the fragment before returning it.

Comment: `Invalidate()` doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I've refreshed the tab names by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` after you've updated the names

```
public void setTabNames(String[] input){
    names = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

From the `PagerAdapter` javadoc:

> This method should be called by the application if the data backing this adapter has changed and associated views should update.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is usually called when you add or remove tabs to a tab host after you've rendered it.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that in your adapter you're returning a new Fragment after each getItem() call. You should set the title of the fragment before returning it.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            TabOne fragTab1 = new TabOne();
            fragTab1.setTitle(names[position]);
            return fragTab1;
        (...)
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then isn't `names` in my `CustomTabAdapter` class. Its not in the actual `TabsViewGUI` class - so would I have use like a get method from `CustomTabAdapter`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. Isn't your `names` variable inside the adapter the array that holds the page titles? The adapter pattern is used to decouple a data set from the ui code that will render that data set, this can be tabs in a tab host, table rows in a table view or whatever. With that said, your adapter should hold all the data required for rendering this page.

Comment: Sorry, forget what I just said - yes you are right - it is in the adpter class. I was clearly looking in the wrong class, but just out of interest will I still need to `invalidate()` - that is `viewpager.invalidate()`?

Comment: @CodeMan no I think you can forget about that invalidate() call :)

Comment: i can't seem to find the `setTitle()` method for the fragment

Comment: Indeed... my mistake there's no such method in fragment class... your  current **public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)** inside the adapter should have done the trick. Are you able to see any default title? A blank place holder in the viewPager?

Comment: Hey Code Man, I'm checking the official documentation there's a good example there. [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: Hi, yes precisely that! Just no names in each tab

Comment: as in the example try to getActionBar(); inside your activity and add tabs to it.